# Conditionally Hiding Tabs with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using the tabs example from the Angular front page.  I want to conditionally hide one of the tabs using a checkbox option (something like 'show advanced'....

```
<pane title="Pluralization" ng-show="showPlural">
```

I have set up an example here...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/michaeldausmann/RJEGY/#base
```

It's not working, the tab just doesn't render properly whether the checkbox is on or not.  Before I dive in and refactor the tabs directive, has anybody already solved this problem?  or is there an alternate tabs implementation that I can try?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out.  Needed to Hack the directive to take a new attribute (showtab) on the pane.

```
  scope: { 
          title: '@',
          tabshow: "="
         },
```

and then ng-hide the elements within the tabs template...

```
  template:
    '<div class="tabbable">' +
      '<ul class="nav {{navclass}}">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}" ng-hide="pane.tabshow==false">'+
          '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
        '</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
      '<div class="{{tclass}} tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
    '</div>',
```

and the pane template

```
  template:
    '<div ng-hide="tabshow==false" class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
    '</div>',
```

Then in the page, use tabshow instead of ng-show..

Check out fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaeldausmann/RJEGY/1/

HTH

Michael